# is it possible to have a drop shadow be a gradient?

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible with css. I want a square that has a drop shadow. At the bottom of the square, the drop shadow is completely visible. At the top of the square, no drop shadow should be apparent. This would be a gradient so being in between the top and bottom, the drop shadow would be half visible.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Does not a `box-shadow` implicitly have a gradient?

Comment: @arxanas I'm talking about a gradient over the entire square, not only an edge.

Comment: Matthew, are you saying you want essentially a 'soft-edge' box-shaped gradient?

Comment: @sscirrus Sure, that's another way to put it I think.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible to *emulate* that using a gradient on an absolutely positioned pseudo-element, with a `z-index` such that it appears underneath its parent element.

HTML:

```
<div class='e'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.e {
    position: relative;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    margin: 1em;
    background: lemonchiffon;
}
.e:before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 10%; left: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(transparent, navy);
    content: '';
}
```

If you want the shadow to have a faded edge, then you'll have to give the pseudo-element an inset shadow (same colour as the background of `.e`'s parent).

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 .5em .5em white;
```

Note that this won't work in IE9 and older. You can use `filter` gradients for those, but *not on pseudo-elements*, so what you would have to do in this case would be to add a child to the element (just for IE) and style it just like you style the pseudo-element.

---

**EDIT**: If you want this to work over an image, gradient background, then I'm afraid it's a bit trickier and it cannot be done using just CSS in IE9 and older. However, in the current versions of the other browsers, this can be achieved using a linear gradient and three radial gradients.

Relevant CSS:

```
.e {
    width: 25em; /* give it whatever width and height you like */
    height: 25em;
    /* make padding on right and bottom larger by adding the amount taken by
     * the "shadow"
     */
    padding: 5% 10% 10% 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* change navy to red in each of these at one time to see what each
     * gradient covers
     */
    background:radial-gradient(at top right, navy, transparent 70.71%) 0 100%,
        radial-gradient(at top left, navy, transparent 70.71%) 100% 100%,
        radial-gradient(at bottom left, navy, transparent 70.71%) 100% 0,
        linear-gradient(navy, transparent) 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 95% 95%, 5%, 5%, 5% 95%, 90% 5%;
}
```

Comment: So close. It looks great except I guess I didn't mention that it's got to work on a background. The box-shadow doesn't look right unless the background is white (or some other solid). But my background is actually either an image or a gradient, nothing solid.

Answer (score 7):

I just had to mock this up for one of my dev's... Maybe useful to someone:

**Code Pen**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOpOMV

**HTML**

```
<div class="element">
  <div class="inner">
    lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah lorem ipsum blahblah 
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.element {
  width:500px; min-height:500px; box-shadow:0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4); margin:0 auto; position:relative;
}
.element:before {
  position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; height:80%; content:''; background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%,#fff 100%);transform:scale(1.2);
}
.inner {
  position:relative; z-index:2; padding:20px;
}
```

**NOTE:** width / height aren't needed.. just there for mocking

Answer (score 0):

CSS3's `box-shadow` property only accepts a `<color>` value and nothing more complicated like an image or CSS gradient, but I can think of a few ways to hack it.

The first is to have a parent element with a gradient background and then an inner shadow applied (where the inner shadow is the same color as the page background, assuming you're okay with a solid color). You then put your actual box inside this.

The alternative is using CSS3 image-borders (using `stretch` instead of tiling). You can generalise a drop-shadow as a specific case of CSS image borders, so just create your own gradient image in Photoshop and make that the border.

Finally, the only other option is CSS2-style of wrapper elements and predefined images. I'd argue this isn't necessary anymore as no-one cares about IE6 and 7 now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

`box-shadow: black 0 -60px 50px -50px inset`

The final value (-50px) clips the shadow back 50px on all sides. Then the second value (-60px) cancels that out in the vertical direction, along the bottom, and adds 10px to the bottom shadow. The third value is the spread, which is how I decided how much to clip the shadow in the fourth value.

But you'll have difficulty using box shadow to do this. You definitely can't cover half the box unless you know the element's height. It's better to just use a background-image property with a CSS3 gradient. Check out this link for details: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-linear-gradient-syntax/

**Edit** OH I think understand what you mean. You actually want a drop shadow, not an inset shadow, but you want it to appear like a gradient. David's answer is more applicable. I can't add comments, but you could use a :before and/or :after pseudo element for his first option.